# Find elements present in one list but not in another list (and vice versa)

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

```
aList = [1, 2]
bList = [2, 3]    
aList = [i for i in aList if i not in bList ]
bList = [i for i in bList if i not in aList ]
print(aList)
print(bList)
```

I expected the result for `aList` and `bList` to be `[1]` and `[3]`, but the result was `[1]` and `[2,3]`.

I thought the `i` in `aList` will disappear after the `aList` is made, and I can use `i` in `bList`.

How does `i` in `aList` affect `i` in `bList`?

Comment: You've modified `aList` by replacing it's value with result of list comprehension, after that `2` is not more exists in `aList` and all items of `bList` pass your filter condition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because when you executed `aList = [i for i in aList if i not in bList ]` , you replaced the content of your `aList` from `[1,2]` to `[1]`.

And hence, `bList` ended up holding both `[2,3]` because your `aList` is just `[1]` while executing `bList = [i for i in bList if i not in aList ]`.

In order to make your logic work, you may store the `aList` and `bList` in different variable. For example:

```
aList = [1,2]
bList = [2,3]    
aListCopy = [i for i in aList if i not in bList ]
bListCopy = [i for i in bList if i not in aList ]
print(aListCopy)   # prints: [1]
print(bListCopy)   # prints: [3]
```

---

However for your use-case, it is **better to use `set()` to find element present in one list but not in another list**. For example:

```
# Returns elements present in `aList` but not in `bList`
>>> set(aList) - set(bList)
set([1]) 

# Returns elements present in `bList` but not in `aList`
>>> set(bList) - set(aList)
set([3])
```

Please refer [`set()` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-set) for more details.

Comment: thanks!, then is it okay to use same variable 'i' for both sentences?

Comment: yes, that is fine. Because while using it inside the *list comprehension*, it will be reassigned the value both the times

Comment: @kw3136, consider using *set* as an alternative to *list*, it will fit better for such as tasks.

Comment: @MoinuddinQuadri, even better to not use lists at all and declare both `aList` and `bList` as sets initially.

Comment: @OlvinRoght that's the expectation. If list is not needed, it's better to declare as set, instead of declaring a list and later type-casting it to set. *But **Note** : `list` are ordered whereas `set` as unordered*

Answer (score 1):

Programs execute step by step. The statement:

```
aList = [i for i in aList if i not in bList ]
```

Replaces the orignial value of `aList` from `[1, 2]` to `[1]`. Then, by the time control reaches this statement:

```
bList = [i for i in bList if i not in aList ]
```

The state is:

```
bList = [i for i in [2, 3] if i not in [1] ]
```

which explains your output.

```
bList = [2, 3]
```

---

There is a way to get around this, use **tuple assignment**:

```
aList, bList =  [i for i in aList if i not in bList ], [i for i in bList if i not in aList ]
```

All values on the left-hand side are updated only after all the right hand side expressions are evaluated.
Now you have:
`aList = [1]`
`bList = [3]`

Also, the scope of `i` in both list comprehensions is only within the comprehension(`[]`).

Answer (score -1):

The problem is you're reusing the variable `aList`. Use a different name in line 3.